# What Subject does the Iron Bracelet use?

Tags: baka-and-test

In Baka and Test, an Avatar's power is determined by the test scores of the subject the field is in. the Iron Bracelet that Aki got allows him to create a field to summon his Avatar and because he is a probationary student, is the only one who can summon their Avatar and help with physical work without the aid of a teacher.

However when Aki's Avatar is hurt it looses points and in one episode in Season 1 when the guys are trying to peak on the girls (i think it's episode 5 where Yūji's eyes keep getting poked out by Shouko because the other girls are in swimsuits, the episode before Yūji's and Shouko's "Wedding") Aki's Avatar's points reach 0 and such Iron Man bursts in and drags Aki out of the hot tub to remedial class.

So i am wondering, since a student's avatar is based off their score of the subject the field is in and in the example above Aki used the Iron Bracelet, so what Subject does the Iron Bracelet use?